# Attempt to de-reference a null object for pagereference method in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

Please help me on this error,

```
    /** sending mail to customer from WO **/

public class Send_Docs_To_Customer {


    public String Subject       {get;set;}
    public String Emailbody     {set;get;}
    public String linkbody      {set;get;}
    private final Work_Order__c WO;

    public String sEmail        {set;get;}
    public String[] toAddresses {set;get;}

    String woid;
    public Id posId             {get;set;}


    public Send_Docs_To_Customer(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

      try{
          posId = controller.getRecord().Id; 
          String fullRecordURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + posId;
          system.debug('Testing the url::::::::'+fullRecordURL);

          System.debug(':::::::::::::Workorder Id:::::::'+posId);



    Work_Order__c wo    = [
                        Select  Id,
                                Contractor__c,
                                Primary_Contact__r.id
                        FROM    Work_Order__c
                        WHERE   id =: apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('ID')
                        ];        


   /** Account acct  =   [
                        SELECT  ID,
                                Name,
                                Project_Management_Lead_Email__c
                        FROM    Account
                        WHERE   ID =: wo.Contractor__c
                            ];
    sEmail = acct.Project_Management_Lead_Email__c;
    System.Debug('Account Email:' +sEmail); **/


      }

     catch(exception e){

    System.Debug('Error message'+e.getMessage());
    System.Debug('Error Line num'+e.getLineNumber());
    }


}

  /**  public Work_Order__c getWO() {

        return WO;

    } **/


    public PageReference send()
    {

        String[] toaddress = new String[]{sEmail};
        String[] arrTest = sEmail.split('\\;');
      //  System.debug('Email :' + toaddress[0]);
        Emailbody =Emailbody+'  \n'+'  \n';
        linkbody='After Pictures:   '+' '+'https://apex/ImageControllervf?id='+ posId +' \n'+'  \n' +'Site Sign Off Documents:   '+' '+'https://apex/Site_signOffvf?id='+ posId;

        Emailbody = Emailbody+linkbody;



         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            email.SetToAddresses(arrTest); 
          //  email.SetToAddresses(toAddresses);
            email.SetSubject(Subject);
            email.SetPlainTextBody(Emailbody);

        try{
           // Sends the email
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email}); 

        }

        catch(exception e){
        system.debug('Error message'+e.getMessage());
        system.debug('Error Line num'+e.getLineNumber());
        }

        return Page.WO_Message;

    }
}
```

And my test class is:

```
    @isTest
private class SendDocs_Test {

    private static testMethod void test() {



        Account contractor = TestData.createContractor();

        Opportunity site = TestData.createSite();
        SoW__c painting = TestData.addSow(TestData.initSow('Painting'),site);

        Estimate__c estimate = TestData.createWorkEstimate(site, new List<SoW__c>{painting});
        estimate.Status__c = 'Accepted Internal';
        update estimate;

        System.AssertEquals('Accepted Internal' , estimate.Status__c);

        // Create WO
        Work_Order__c wo = WorkOrderUtil.createFor(estimate, contractor.id);
        wo.Amount__c = 1000;
        wo.status__c = WorkOrderUtil.STATUS_ISSUED;
        wo.Tax_Amount__c = 50;
        insert wo;
        System.debug('WOrk Order:;;;;;;;;;;;;'+ wo.id);

         String sEmail = 'me@email1.com';
         String[] toaddress = new String[]{sEmail};
          String[] arrTest = sEmail.split('\\;');
         String Emailbody ;
         Emailbody = Emailbody+'  \n'+'  \n';
         String linkbody;
         linkbody = 'After and Site Sign off pictures';
         Emailbody = Emailbody+linkbody;
         String Subject = 'My subject';

            PageReference pageRef = Page.Send_Docs_Customer_vf;
            Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

             PageReference ref  = Page.Site_signOffvf;
             Test.setCurrentPage(ref);

            PageReference ref1  = Page.ImageControllervf;
             Test.setCurrentPage(ref1);

             PageReference ref2  = Page.WO_Message;
             Test.setCurrentPage(ref2);

            pageRef.getParameters().put('id',wo.id);
            ref.getParameters().put('id',wo.id);
           ref1.getParameters().put('id',wo.id);

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email =   new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();


            email.SetToAddresses(arrTest);
            email.SetSubject(Subject);
            email.SetPlainTextBody(Emailbody);

       Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email}); 



        Test.StartTest();
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(wo);
        Send_Docs_To_Customer sd = new Send_Docs_To_Customer(sc);

            sd.send(); (***""""""""""I am getting error here'''''''''''''***)
           // System.assertEquals( true, result);
          //  System.assertNotEquals(null, result);
        Test.StopTest();

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the line of the error?

Comment: You never actually set `sEmail` on your controller instance.